# Почему происходит ошибка cocos2dx на андроид?

Tags: android, кросс-компиляция, cocos2d-x

Я пытаюсь собрать пример на `android`, сам пример создается, но при компиляции вылазит ошибка.

У меня:

`windows 10`;

`cocos2dx 4.0` (версии ниже жаловались на чрезмерно современный `sdk`);

`sdk` и `ndk` установлены `Android Studio`;

`cmake` установлен вручную (версия `3.21`);

В чём суть ошибки и как её исправить?

Вот ошибка:

```
Creating configuration testReleaseRuntimeOnly
Creating configuration testReleaseCompileOnly
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp
Creating configuration testReleaseAnnotationProcessor
Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
SDK initialized in 0 ms

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':MyGame'.
> Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901-dirty

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Error running command, return code: 1.
```

Comment: Ох, когда же вы уже научитесь читать ошибки... `Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901-dirty`

Comment: ок, что значит эта ошибка, гугл не дает результатов

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема, вот как я ее решил:

1. Убедитесь, что у вас установлена версия 3.18.1 CMake. (Вы можете проверить это, перейдя в: SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Show Package Details (флажок в правом нижнем углу) -> CMake -> флажок версии 3.18.1 -> применить
2. Затем я обновил версию com.android.tools.build. У меня было: 3.5.1, обновлено до 4.2.2. Перейдите в build.gradle (**не в папке app**) и заменил в блоке dependencies на

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

3. На последнем шаге я изменил дистрибутив (gradle (папка) -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties) и заменил его более новой версией:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

После всех этих шагов синхронизация была выполнена правильно. Надеюсь, я вам помог :)

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, ваш ответ на русский язык (нажав [edit])

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin на англо-язычных ресурсах действительно нет решения данной проблемы, хотелось ответить так, чтобы эту проблему решили не только наши соотечественники :)